# How to access DB config in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

In my application, I need to know what values are assigned to the DB config items such as `database`, `username`, etc. How do I access those information?

Comment: Need to know or need to set? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: No. I need to "get" the information.

Comment: @Rupesh Pawar's answer should work

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can retrieve it with this:
    http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

```
$this->config->item('item name');
```

Comment: Except it's not a config item. Config items are stored in the `$config` array. I'm trying to access database configuration stored in $db array.

Comment: Try echo $this->db->database;

Comment: I've seen that on the net and tried it. Doesn't work. Wondering if it's a version thing. I'm using latest CI.

Comment: Can you try $this->config->item('username', 'database'); ?

Comment: echo $this->db->hostname; for example

Answer (score 58):

I don't have enough rep to comment on Matt Browne's correct answer but just adding a bit incase anyone forgets...

load the db driver like so first:

```
$this->load->database();
```

then you can easily access what you need:

```
$this->db->hostname
$this->db->username
$this->db->password
$this->db->database
```

Comment: how to get all config defined in database.php at once?

Answer (score 9):

Pretty much all the config values are accessible via $this->db (take a look at system/database/DB_driver.php).

That's what worked for me...none of the other suggestions here did.

As an example

```
$config = [ 
     'host'     => $this->db->hostname,
     'port'     => '3306',
     'username' => $this->db->username,
     'password' => $this->db->password,
     'database' => $this->db->database
];
```

For more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23666778/560114

Answer (score 7):

In case you have multiple database connection groups defined in config/database.php, for eg :

```
  $db['dbname']['hostname'] = "localhost";
  $db['dbname']['username'] = "root";
  $db['dbname']['password'] = "root";
  $db['dbname']['database'] = "web_dbname";

  $db['dbname_readonly']['hostname'] = "localhost";
  $db['dbname_readonly']['username'] = "root";
  $db['dbname_readonly']['password'] = "root";
  $db['dbname_readonly']['database'] = "web_dbname_readonly";
```

If you want to use the connection params of any particular db in a controller or model:

```
  $db = $this->load->database('dbname');
```

If you want to use in a helper or library :

```
  $ci = &get_instance();
  $db = $ci->load->database('dbname');
```

The connection params will be available as $db->hostname, $db->username etc.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this, looking for a way to find **all** of the DB settings.  Was not able to find a solution on-line, but found some useful code in `system/database/DB.php`

Here's my approach, get the contents of the entire database config:

```
    if ( ! file_exists($f = APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/database.php')
        && ! file_exists($f = APPPATH.'config/database.php'))
    {
        show_error('The configuration file database.php does not exist.');
    }

    include($f);

    // Use a NEW variable.  
    // Because $db is a reserved name!!
    $db_settings = $db;

    foreach($db_settings as $key => $value) {
        // .. do something with .. $this->database->load($key);
        // .. do something with .. $value['database'];
        // .. do something with .. $value['password'];
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to get at your configuration setting like this :

```
$this->config['env']
```

Comment: I downvoted this because it didn't work at all for me...did it work in a previous version of CodeIgniter or something?